# How type inference work for method calls?

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following example:

```
public class Learn {
    public static <T> T test (T a, T b) {
        System.out.println(a.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(b.getClass().getSimpleName());
        b = a;
        return a;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        test("", new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
}
```

In the `main` method, I am calling `test` with a `String` and an `ArrayList <Integer>` object. Both are different things and assigning an `ArrayList` to `String` (generally) gives a compile error.

```
String aString = new ArrayList <Integer> (); // won't compile
```

But I am doing exactly that in the 3rd line of `test` and the program compiles and runs fine. First I thought that the type parameter `T` is replaced by a type that's compatible with both `String` and `ArrayList` (like `Serializable`). But the two `println` statements inside `test` print "String" and "ArrayList" as types of `a` and `b` respectively. My question is, if `a`is `String` and `b` is `ArrayList` at runtime, how can we assign `a` to `b`.

Comment: Hint: you're confusing the static types of `a` and `b` with their dynamic types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a generic method, the Java compiler will [infer the most specific common type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) for both parameters `a` and `b`.

> The inference algorithm determines the types of the arguments and, if available, the type that the result is being assigned, or returned. Finally, the inference algorithm tries to find the most *specific* type that works with all of the arguments.

You aren't assigning the result of the call to `test` to anything, so there is no target to influence the inference.

In this case, even `String` and `ArrayList<Integer>` have a common supertype, `Serializable`, so `T` is inferred as `Serializable`, and you can always assign one variable of the same type to another.  For other examples, you may even find `Object` as the common supertype.

But just because you have variables of type `T` that are inferred as `Serializable`, the objects themselves are still a `String` and an `ArrayList`, so getting their classes and printing their names still prints `String` and `ArrayList`.  You're not printing the type of the variables; you're printing the type of the objects.

Comment: Hey thanks. But can you explain why the program prints "String" and "ArrayList" and not "Object" and "Object"?

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal The inferred type is `Serializable` (or whatever type that is the most specific common ancestor of `String` and `ArrayList`) and that's why it compiles, but at _runtime_, the types are still `String` and `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I did this: `Object ob = new String (); System.out.println(ob.getClass().getSimpleName());`. It prints "String"  and now I understand what's happening.

Comment: @rgettman I think I fully understand this, but just to be extra sure...the code prints what it prints because of dynamic method dispatch, right?

Comment: No dynamic dispatch _effects_ here.  At runtime, dynamic dispatch is used to attempt to find the proper override of a non-static method call on an object.  But here, no class is overriding `getClass`, which is `final` in `Object`.  It is already defined to return the proper `Class` object.  The call to `getName()` is on the `Class` object, and the `Class` class is itself `final`.  So while technically every non-static Java object method call goes through dynamic dispatch, it is effectively irrelevant here.

Comment: I did not know `getClass` is defined as final. The comment explained a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: It's a bit tricky in Java because that has type erasure, but conceptually, what you expected is the result of printing `T.getSimpleName()` while you are asking about `a.getClass().getSimpleName()`. Or, again put differently, `a` and `b` are actually of types `TA` and `TB` respectively, where both inherit from a common class `T`. You pass `a` to your function as a `T`, then call `getClass()` on it an expected to see `T` again instead of `TA`.

Answer (score 3):

```
test("", new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
Learn.test("", new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Which is also equivalent to the following:

```
Learn.<Serializable>test("", new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

This will not compile if you explicitly specify a generic type other than `Serializable` (or `Object`), such as `String`:

```
Learn.<String>test("", new ArrayList<Integer>()); // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

So essentially both parameters are treated as `Serializable` in your case.