# How to don't allow Type Inference and require a explicit type on method call?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I'm currently building a class with a Pair-Structure. I want to somehow guarantee that each member of the pair has the exact same type.

My question goes in the direction of: [How type inference work for method calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007890/how-type-inference-work-for-method-calls)

Following code illustrates my problem:

```java
public class MyClass {    
    public class MyPair<E> {
        private E oldObj;
        private E newObj;

        MyPair(E pOldObj, E pNewObj) {
            oldObj = pOldObj;
            newObj = pNewObj;
        }
    }
    public class MyObject {
        List<MyPair<?>> listWithPairs = new ArrayList<>();

        public <T> void addPair(T oldObj, T newObj) {
            listWithPairs.add(new MyPair<T>(oldObj, newObj));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject pairHolder = new MyObject();
        pairHolder.addPair(12L, "asdf");//Call 1
        pairHolder.<Long>addPair(12L, 12L);//Call 2
    }
}
```

Is there a way in Java to make Call 1 impossible and always require a type specification like in Call 2?

Comment: Where's `listWithPairs` declared? And how come the `static main` method is calling the `addPair` instance method? Please post code that would compile and that is complete.

Comment: Sry, was a bit silly. I posted a runnable example

Comment: Good question, but I seem to have found a duplicate.

Comment: Fair enough, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem but gives me a reasonable answer.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with inference? Nothing will stop a caller from doing `pairHolder.<Object>addPair(12L, "asdf");`, so forcing a type parameter doesn't really gain you anything. So I'll ask a different way: What are you *really* trying to achieve by "disabling" inference?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps by declaring your method like that way

```
public <T extends Number> void addPair(T oldObj, T newObj) {
        listWithPairs.add(new MyPair<T>(oldObj, newObj));
}
```